# AWS GlueContext getSink Vs write_dynamic_frame_from_options

Tags: aws-glue

I am working on a solution where I am writing a Glue job (PySpark)to read a csv file and save it as a parquet file.
I am using the api `create_dynamic_frame_from_options` to read the CSV.  [Documented here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-glue-context.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-glue-context-create_dynamic_frame_from_options).

I then perform some transformation and write the DynamicFrame using `write_dynamic_frame_from_options` by specifying the `format = "parquet"`.

I can also see a `getSink` api available to write DynamicFrame.

I am not sure I get the difference between the two or if one should be preferred over other and in what scenarios.